# multicolumn-command which automatically uses all columns of the table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Is it possible to define a `multicolumn{}{}{}`-command, which *automatically* spans **all columns** of a table?

For my longtables I want to use a command defined in the preamble, which typesets at the right lower edge (raggedleft) a message, that the table will be continued on the following page.

As my longtables have different numbers of columns, I don't know how to define that general command. Is there a counter which reads the number of columns for the actual table and could be used?

---

edit: I found in the [manual of the longtable package](http://dante.ctan.org/get/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) that there is an internal counter **`\LT@cols`**, but I don't see how I could use it for the multicolumn-command - I even am not able to print its value in the document.

---

edit 3: with Herbert's code it works.

```
\makeatletter
\def\LongtableFooter{%
  \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{r}{\scriptsize to be continued on following page}\\}
\makeatother
```

---

### Example:

*(remark: as the second longtable in the example has only 4 columns, the command with `\multicolumn{5}` naturally failed.)*

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}

%\newcommand{\LongtableFooter}{\multicolumn{5}{r}\mbox{to be continued on following page}}

\makeatletter
\def\LongtableFooter{%
  \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{r}{\scriptsize to be continued on following page}\\}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

here comes the table with the pagebreak

\vspace{0.6\textheight}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}ll}

\toprule
A & B & C & D & E\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\mbox{table continued from last page}\\
\toprule
A & B & C & D\\

\midrule
\endhead
%\bottomrule
\LongtableFooter
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

a & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
 a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
\midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
\end{longtable}




And here it fails, as there are only 4 columns:

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}ll}

\toprule
A & B & C & D\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\mbox{table continued from last page}\\
\toprule
A & B & C & D\\
\midrule
\endhead
%\bottomrule
\LongtableFooter
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
  & b & c & d\\
   & b & c & d\\
    & b & c & d\\*
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
 \midrule
 a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
 \midrule
 a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
\midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\*
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 \midrule
a & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the `tabu` package allows this. It includes a lot of tricky features.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thank you - `tabu` might help. However, I don't dare adding just another such complex package to my preamble, as it could have effects on many other tables as well. In that case I would just set the column-number as a variable in my command and define it for each longtable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\LongtableFooter{%
  \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{r}{to be continued on following page}\\}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thank you, looks promising, however if I replace my command with your lines in my example, it is printed only in the last footer and _before_ the `bottomrule` - what am I doing wrong? **(see/try changed minimal example in my question)**

Comment: @Martin: I had a nice bug ... :-) `\def\LongtableFooter#1{` was the problem, I forgot to delete the `#1` in my example. Now corrected