# multicolumn in longtable with span dependant on number of columns

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

How can I use `\multicolumn` in a `longtable` environment to span all columns except for one? The `\LT@cols` counter is probably the way to go. However, doing arithmetics in LaTeX seems somewhat unconventional. Related to [multicolumn-command which automatically uses all columns of the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23196/multicolumn-command-which-automatically-uses-all-columns-of-the-table). What's needed is "`\LT@cols` minus one".

Comment: You can use `\numexpr\LT@cols-1`. Without a MWE, answers too will be trivial ;)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\numexpr\LT@cols-1` and define your own `multicolumn` command like

```
\makeatletter
\def\mymc#1#2{%
  \multicolumn{\numexpr\LT@cols-1}{#1}{#2}%              %%#1 = alignment, #2 = content
}
\makeatother
```

and use it like

```
\mymc{r}{abc}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\mymc#1#2{%
  \multicolumn{\numexpr\LT@cols-1}{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}ll}

\toprule
A & B & C & D & E\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\mbox{table continued from last page}\\
\toprule
A & B & C & D\\

\midrule
\endhead
%\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\mymc{r}{abc} & d\\
 \midrule
a & \mymc{c}{bcd}\\
 & b & c & d\\
 & b & c & d\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Harish's answer have helped me to achieve what I wanted. \numexpr is the answer I was looking for. Thank you guys!