# Keep sorting local to groups for symbols in glossaries-extra with bib2gls

Tags: sorting, grouping, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[record,style=alttreegroup,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{filecontents}{symbols.bib}
@symbol{alpha,
name = {\ensuremath{\alpha}},
description = {angle},
group = {greek},
}
@symbol{theta,
name = {\ensuremath{\theta}},
description = {for testing},
group = {greek},
}
@symbol{diffusion,
name = {\ensuremath{D}},
description = {diffusion factor},
group = {roman},
}
@symbol{choke,
name = {\ensuremath{\mathrm{cor}}},
description = {corrected},
group = {sub},
}
@symbol{blockage,
name = {\ensuremath{B}},
description = {blockage factor},
group = {roman},
}
\end{filecontents}

\GlsXtrLoadResources % input file created by bib2gls
[% instructions to bib2gls:
    src={symbols},
    type = symbols,
    selection = {all},%
%   symbol-sort-fallback={name},%turning off makes it worse
]

\setglossarypreamble[symbols]{\glssetwidest{MMM}}

\begin{document}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{roman}{Roman Letters}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Letters}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{sub}{Subscripts}

\printunsrtglossaries % iterate over all defined entries
\end{document}
```

It produces this results:

[image]

It is quickly clear what is wrong here. The sorting works *globally* when building the document as

```
pdflatex document
bib2gls document
pdflatex document
```

as [shown here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml). Running `bib2gls -g document` did not seem to make a difference.

**How can the groups be kept separate and sorting local to them, without mixing of groups?**

A possible workaround I thought of would be to have different `types` for *Roman*, *Greek* etc. and then call them all manually (as opposed to one `type` for `symbols`). But that seems not the right way. I feel like I am very close to the solution, but the last steps I could not find help with in the doc.

## Edit 1:

After [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481360/120853), the core question was solved. The solution was found in the `bib2gls` documentation (and not `glossaries-user`, `glossaries-code` or `glossaries-extra` package docs!).

While working, I found there is not a lot of novice-friendly material out there yet (aside from the excellent websites at Dickimaw). With that I mean hands-on examples that give a working baseline, and not just snippets. Therefore, I am uploading my current code for reference. It has a handful of concepts in it that might be helpful. It will have numerous issues still, but hopefully it serves people as a starting point to see what is possible, what the syntax is like, what commands there are, etc.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage[abbreviations, symbols, record, nomain]{glossaries-extra}
% Record for bib2gls to work.
% Nomain, aka no default glossary
% Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477658/120853
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% New Glossary 'types'. Load data into them from *.bib-files, then run bib2gls
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Using Abbreviations/Symbols package options creates these glossaries already.
% Create the rest manually.
\newglossary*{subsuper}{Sub- and Superscripts}%

% Select all files in bib.
% Not a good approach, but bib2gls seems to have problems with 'subimport'.
\GlsXtrLoadResources[%
    src={./glossaries/abbreviations},%
    selection = {all},%
]%
\GlsXtrLoadResources[%
    src={./glossaries/symbols},%
    selection = {all},% grab all from bib-file. Using subimport currently does not work
    sort-field={group},%sort by this field first
    sort-suffix={name},%append this field as suffix to sort-field
    symbol-sort-fallback={description},% fall back to description if absolutely required
]%
\GlsXtrLoadResources[%
    src={./glossaries/subsuper},%
    type=subsuper,%
    category = subsuper,
    selection = {all},% grab all from bib-file. Using subimport currently does not work
    sort-field={group},%sort by this field first
    sort-suffix={name},%append this field as suffix to sort-field
    symbol-sort-fallback={description},% fall back to description if absolutely required
]%

% indexonlyfirst can also be a package option.
% Index only on first use for certain categories, as set manually above.
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318886/120853
% Symbols has type=symbols but category=symbol (singular)
\glssetcategoryattribute{symbol}{indexonlyfirst}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{other}{indexonlyfirst}{true}

% Each bib-entry has a group-field.
% bib2gls is smart and would take grouptitles from there, but those are just variables.
% Give proper names for all groups here.
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{sub}{Subscripts}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{super}{Superscripts}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{roman}{Roman}

% One down in rprt/book
\setglossarysection{section}

% More Width
\setglossarypreamble[subsuper]{\glssetwidest{MMM}}%

% Remove from ToC (doing this manually).
% Default is true.
\glstocfalse
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% New Styles as longtables
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{glossary-mcols}%multi-column styles
\usepackage{glossary-longextra}

\newcommand*{\glshdrfont}[1]{\sffamily\large\textbf{#1}}% font for gls table heads
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mltcolspan}[2]{\multicolumn{\numexpr\LT@cols}{#1}{#2}} % multicolumn spanning all columns automatically. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168358/120853
\makeatother

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269571/120853
    \setglossarystyle{long-name-desc}% base new style on existing one

    \renewcommand{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
        \glshdrfont{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} & \glshdrfont{Description} & \glshdrfont{\nth{1} Use} & \glshdrfont{Unit}\tabularnewline
    }%

    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type
    \begin{longtable}{rp{0.8\glsdescwidth}rl}}%
    {\end{longtable}}

    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        %empty first header
        \endfirsthead
        \mltcolspan{c}{\textit{(\expandafter\MakeUppercase\currentglossary{} continued)}}\\
        \endhead
    }%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription & ##2 & \glsentryuseri{##1}\tabularnewline
    }%use glsentryuseri to access entry, not glsuseri https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281772/120853
}

\newglossarystyle{myacr}{%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269571/120853
    \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type
    \begin{longtable}{lp{0.9\glsdescwidth}l}}%
    {\end{longtable}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
        \glshdrfont{Short} & \glshdrfont{Description} & \glshdrfont{Pages}\\
        \endfirsthead
        \mltcolspan{c}{\textit{(\expandafter\MakeUppercase\currentglossary{} continued)}}\\
        \glshdrfont{Short} & \glshdrfont{Description} & \glshdrfont{Pages}\\
        \endhead%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}%
        & \glossentrydesc{##1} & ##2 \tabularnewline % Description
%       & ##2 \tabularnewline
    }%
}

\begin{filecontents}{symbols.bib}
@symbol{density,
name = {\ensuremath{\rho}},
description = {density},
group = {greek},
user1 = {\si{\kilogram\per\meter\cubed}},
}
@symbol{viscosity,
name = {\ensuremath{\mu}},
description = {(dynamic) viscosity},
group = {greek},
user1 = {\si{\pascal\second}},
}
@symbol{work,
name = {\ensuremath{W}},
description = {work},
group = {roman},
user1 = {\si{\joule}},
}
@symbol{specwork,
name = {\ensuremath{w}},
description = {specific work},
group = {roman},
user1 = {\si{\joule\per\kilogram}},
}
@symbol{heatingvalue,
name = {\ensuremath{H}},
description = {(specific) heating value},
group = {roman},
user1 = {\si{\joule\per\kilogram}},
}
@symbol{molarmass,
name = {\ensuremath{M}},
description = {molar mass},
group = {roman},
user1 = {\si{\kilogram\per\mole}},
}
@symbol{torque,
name = {\ensuremath{M}},
description = {torque},
group = {roman},
user1 = {\si{\newton\meter}},
}
@symbol{substance,
name = {\ensuremath{n}},
description = {amount of substance},
group = {roman},
user1 = {\si{\mole}},
}
@symbol{rotspeed,
name = {\ensuremath{n}},
description = {rotational speed},
group = {roman},
user1 = {\si{\per\second}},
}
@symbol{shearstress,
name = {\ensuremath{\tau}},
description = {shear stress},
group = {greek},
user1 = {\si{\newton\per\meter\squared}},
}
@symbol{boundarythickness,
name = {\ensuremath{\delta}},
description = {boundary layer thickness},
group = {greek},
user1 = {\si{\meter}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{abbreviations.bib}
@abbreviation{ode,
  short = {ODE},
  long = {Ordinary Differential Equation}
}

@abbreviation{rms,
  short = {RMS},
  long = {Root Mean Square}
}

@abbreviation{mad,
  short = {MAD},
  long = {Median Absolute Deviation}
}

@abbreviation{cv,
  short = {CV},
  long = {Coefficient of Variation}
}

@abbreviation{cfd,
  short = {CFD},
  long = {Computational Fluid Dynamics}
}

@abbreviation{cht,
  short = {CHT},
  long = {Computational Heat Transfer}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{subsuper.bib}
@symbol{mean,
name = {\ensuremath{\bar{X}}},
description = {mean},
group = {super},
user1 = {varies},
}
@symbol{median,
name = {\ensuremath{\widetilde{X}}},
description = {median},
group = {super},
user1 = {varies},
}
@symbol{total,
name = {tot},
description = {total conditions},
group = {sub},
user1 = {--},
}
@symbol{molar,
name = {mol},
description = {molar},
group = {sub},
user1 = {--},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
% In KOMA, create chapter+ToC entry but unnumbered
\addchap{Nomenclature}
\textit{The most commonly used symbols are listed here, alongside their location of first occurrence. Symbols used but not listed here are clarified in their respective contexts.}
\printunsrtglossary[type = symbols, style = symbunitlong]
\printunsrtglossary[type = subsuper, style = mcolalttreegroup]
\printunsrtglossary[type = abbreviations, style = myacr]
\end{document}
```

It looks like:
[image]

I would be happy to receive feedback. Perhaps, this question hits enough keywords to help people lost on Google in the future (like I was). Note that the generation requires

```
pdflatex
bib2gls
pdflatex
```

Comment: For reference, I indeed ended up splitting the one `*.bib`-file into all respective parts. Each is then invoked using a newly defined type via e.g. `\newglossary*{greek}{Greek}`. I then `\printunsrtglossary[type = greek, style = mystyle]`. This has disadvantages (mainly more manual work), but also gives good control. Symbols can receive their own style (using `mystyle`) which can involve units, and abbreviations receive a different style.  This would not be possible with just `\printunsrtglossaries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't claim that the docu is very clear here. But it seems to work if you set the `sort-field` to group and perhaps a second field as `sort-suffix`. The bib2gls-call was `bib2gls --group file` (the `--group` option isn't really needed in this example, but if you have entries without `group` field, it will create a title for them).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[record,style=alttreegroup,nomain,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{filecontents}{symbols.bib}
@symbol{alpha,
name = {\ensuremath{\alpha}},
description = {angle},
group = {greek},
}
@symbol{theta,
name = {\ensuremath{\theta}},
description = {for testing},
group = {greek},
}
@symbol{test,
name = {test},
description = {aaa for testing},
group = {greek},
}
@symbol{diffusion,
name = {\ensuremath{D}},
description = {diffusion factor},
group = {roman},
}
@symbol{choke,
name = {\ensuremath{\mathrm{cor}}},
description = {corrected},
group = {sub},
}
@symbol{blockage,
name = {\ensuremath{B}},
description = {blockage factor},
group = {roman},
}
\end{filecontents}

\GlsXtrLoadResources % input file created by bib2gls
[% instructions to bib2gls:
    src={symbols},
    type = symbols,
    selection = {all},%
    sort-field={group}, 
    sort-suffix={description}   
]


\setglossarypreamble[symbols]{\glssetwidest{MMM}}

\begin{document}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{roman}{Roman Letters}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Letters}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{sub}{Subscripts}

\printunsrtglossaries % iterate over all defined entries
\end{document}
```

[image]