# Determining the number of columns of a table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Table header} \\ \hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I use a multi-column that spans the whole table.

Is it possible to determine the number of columns automatically, e.g., by defining a command for creating a multi-column that spans all columns comprising the table?

This [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23196/multicolumn-command-which-automatically-uses-all-columns-of-the-table) seems to be specific to the `longtable` package.

Comment: short answer no, latex does not have this information by default, there is some code in longtable that you could extract (it doesn't really depend on the rest of the package) it's slightly complicated because the preamble part `{|c|c|c|}` here might be bigger than the actual table, eg ams matrices have a 10 column preamble even if they have fewer actual columns, so if  you have `|c|c|c|` but only two items in each row, tex discards the final `c|` but do you want the answer to be 3 or 2.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there something keeping you from counting the number of columns in the argument of `\begin{tabular}{...}`?

Comment: @Mico Do you mean counting the number of columns manually? If yes, the correct answer is laziness. However, if you refer to an automatic solution--well, I have no idea at the moment how to parse such an complex argument involving the `S` column type from the `siunitx` package and much more ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically agree with the previous comments.

However, if you really want do this because the table will be generated programatically, and the number of column can change accordingly, yo can count the number of column by using list processing provided by  `etoolbox`  or by `listofitems`. Assuming that *you keep te `|` between the columns*,  you  can put in your preamble (`etoòlbox`'s `\doccsvlist`):

```
\global\newcounter{colno}
\setcounter{colno}{0}
\DeclareListParser{\countcol}{|}%
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{colno}}
\newenvironment{newtabular}[1]{
\countcol{#1}%
\begin{tabular}{#1}}%
{\end{tabular}}
```

and in the body :

```
\begin{newtabular}{|c|l|r|c|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{\thecolno}{|c|}{Table header}\\
\hline
A & a & b & c & d\\
\thecolno & \the\numexpr\value{colno}-2\relax& 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{newtabular}
```

Note that the number of columns can also be used in the content of the table.