# Is there a multicolumn ALL (number of columns)?

Tags: tables, tabularray

I would like to be able to define a within-the-tabular line that spans the entire table.  (This is useful, e.g., to throw a table note below a \bottomrule and have it be typeset in the same box without further complications; or to define a header line in the middle of the table.)

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
  \multicolumnall{c}{test}
\end{tabular}
```

If I knew the number of columns, I could use it, but this seems to be a harder problem ([Determining the number of columns of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438006/determining-the-number-of-columns-of-a-table)).  I use lualatex now, so this could make for an argument counting solution, but given that I define my own array specifiers, this would be difficult.

Is there an easy solution, or is this a tough problem?  If it is tough, it is not worth the effort.

advice appreciated, as always.

Comment: no it is hard as thenumber of columns doesn't need to be specified, the argument could be `{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}` and any unused columns simply vanish, that is how ams matrices work, although you could look at the code longtable uses to get a value that corresponds to the specified argument

Comment: Did you have a look at `threeparttable`?

Comment: thx, david.  interesting.  this is probably the easiest trick to solve my problem and therefore the best solution.  thx, enrico.  threeparttable is 20 years old and I figured it was not serious, because DC did not even give an example in the documentation.  Alas, it does seem like another interesting solution to this and another problem I had.  I should use it...

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative solution with `tblr` environment and `\SetCell` command of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. The package provides counters `rowcount` and `colcount` to users.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={lcr}}
\toprule
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\midrule
 \SetCell[c=\thecolcount]{l}
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha  \\
\midrule
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\bottomrule
 \SetCell[c=\thecolcount]{l}
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha  \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice --- I always worry more about accidental incompatibilities with full replacements.  but I think I will try to see how far this one gets me.

Answer (score 2):

In OpTeX, it is very simple:

```
\table{lrrcc}{
  a & b & c & d & e \cr
  \mspan\colnum[c]{text} \cr
  d & e & f & g & h \cr  
}    
\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the command `\Block` has that functionnality.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lrrr}[hvlines]
  \Block{1-*}{title} \\
text & text & text & text 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]